# android room not null constraint failed on insert

Tags: php, android, retrofit, android-room

Im using retrofit as the api and room for database access in my android app. the data received from my backend looks like this

```
[{"category_id":8},{"category_name":"Appetizers"},{"category_image":"upload\/images\/1229-2016-08-30.jpg"},{"category_id":5},{"category_name":"Breakfast"},{"category_image":"upload\/images\/6307-2016-08-30.jpg"},{"category_id":2},{"category_name":"Desserts"},{"category_image":"upload\/images\/0062-2016-08-30.jpg"},{"category_id":1},{"category_name":"Drink"},{"category_image":"upload\/images\/9359-2016-08-30.jpg"},{"category_id":4},{"category_name":"Main Dish"},{"category_image":"upload\/images\/2031-2016-08-30.jpg"},{"category_id":3},{"category_name":"Side Dish"},{"category_image":"upload\/images\/3824-2016-08-30.jpg"}]
```

and my room entity looks like this

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["category_id"])
data class MenuCategories(
        @field:SerializedName("category_id")
        val category_id: String,

        @field:SerializedName("category_name")
        val category_name: String,

        @field:SerializedName("category_image")
        val category_image: String
)
```

and how my dao saves the data

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertMenuCategories(categories: List<MenuCategories>)
```

however i get this error messsage

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1299) abort at 8 in [INSERT OR REPLACE INTO `MenuCategories`(`category_id`,`category_name`,`category_image`) VALUES (?,?,?)]: NOT NULL constraint failed: MenuCategories.category_name
```

Comment: You need to add category_id, category_name, category_image inside one jsonobject

Comment: how do you style the examples btw like the way you've edited mine @AjayS

Comment: You just need to select the content which you want to format then press `Ctrl` + `K`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `category_id`, `category_name`, `category_image` inside one JsonObject like below

```
[
    {
      "category_id": 8,
      "category_name": "Appetizers",
      "category_image": "upload\/images\/1229-2016-08-30.jpg"
    }, {
       .....
    }
]
```

Comment: but i need an array of those